# How to get values in reverse with loops

Tags: visual-studio-2010, variables, loops

The issue is with the bottom of my code where I have to get the program to recite the entered values in reverse order. I think it might be something to do with the index?

Option Explicit On
Option Strict On

'Author: Murray Spears 
'Date: October 12th 2012

'Write a program that accepts five input values and stores them into an array.
'Then display numbers in reverse order.
'Then display the average number, and all numbers that are are above average.

Imports System

Module Values

```
Sub Main()
    Dim Number(4) as Integer
    Dim Average as Double = 0
    Dim Index as integer
'   
  For Index = 0 to 4
  Console.Write("Enter number: ")
  Number(Index)=Convert.ToInt32(Console.Readline())
  Next Index

'Figure out the average for all the entered values.
Average = (Number(0)+Number(1)+Number(2)+Number(3)+Number(4))/5
Console.Writeline("The average of the numbers is: " &Average)

Console.Write("Numbers that are greater than the average: ")
Index = 4
Do until Index = 0
If Number(Index) > Average then 
Console.Writeline(Number(Index))
End If
Index -=1
Loop


Console.Writeline("Numbers in reverse order: ")
Index = 4
Do while Number(index) > 0
Console.Writeline(Number(Index))
Number(index) -= 1
Loop

End Sub
```

End Module

Comment: Step through the problem loop line by line and keep an eye on your variable values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Step -1` to step backwards.

```
For Index = 4 To 0 Step -1
    ' do your thing
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

Imo, the simplest way is to just use a loop as you did when you entered the numbers but as you wrote yourself make the indexes go in reverse.
This is what the "Step -1" is for.

```
For Index As Integer = 4 To 0 Step -1
  Console.Writeline(Number(Index))
Next
```